# PreUpgrade and PostUpgrade option is not showing up in Packagemaker

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker

I add trying to add PreUpgrade and Post Upgrade script in the existing pmdoc file created for a project.but under script section I am only getting only three Text box i.e for Script Directory, PreInstall and PostInstall.I am not getting Post Upgrade and Pre Upgrade text box.
I dont know how to bring those option

Answer (score 0):

After further analysis I found that If I change the minimum Target to 10.4 from 10.5  in Install Properties I am able to get those options.